# Why doesn't Visual Studio Default.aspx file let me add HTML elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2017

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="XEx02Quotation._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <html>
     <head runat="server">
       <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
   </html> 
</asp:Content>
```

I am confuse about why Visual Studio 2017 doesn't let me add HTML elements into the Default.aspx, but what I do know is that under the Solution Explorer, I see master page and apparently they are bind to the content page (which is the Default.aspx). Also, I put a copy of my screenshot problems.

So my question is do I start putting content (HTML elements) inside of that master page first!

Aside from what I have mentioned above, I also notice that when I try to put basic HTML elements into the @page directive (Default.aspx file), it says "“Content  is not supported outside of 'script' or 'asp:Content' Regions” ". 
The only reason I know of these terms is because I research this problem. Here are the article that I have researched. "Content Not Supposed to Be Outside 'Script' or 'asp:Content' Regions"  AND https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx

Here are the screenshot problems: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe something related to putting a new HTML file inside the content? Can you try to put only a ```<div>``` or something else?

Comment: @ Felipe Augusto What do you mean?

Comment: The ```Default.aspx``` is inside the ```Site.Master```, which is a html page, and you're trying to define a html tag inside the ```Default.aspx```, if you try to put a div inside the ```Default.aspx``` the same happens (error)?

Comment: @Felipe Augusto Yes, the same thing happens!

Comment: In my Default.aspx I have a tag like this: ```<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">``` and after I'm able to put my html code and finally the tag closes like this: ```</asp:Content>```, can you try to put these tags? (this tag is after the Page tag)

Comment: @Felipe Augusto I should be able to work in the Default.aspx file, right? Place the HTML elements inside of that.

Comment: I think so! I removed the tags I told you and the same error appeared here, can you try to put these tags?

Comment: @Felipe Augusto I going to edit my answer in a code snippet above with the Default.aspx file. Hold on!

Comment: @Felipe Augusto  I changed the Default.aspx code but I still get an error with the first html tag. Do you know why?

Comment: Is the error exactly the same?

Comment: @Felipe Augusto Yes, 'Element 'html' cannot be nested within element 'div'. I know what the error message means, but it doesn't make sense since I don't even have a 'div' element at the beginning. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, the elements are inside the ```div``` because ```Default.aspx``` is called inside the ```Site.Master```. You can see that with a tag like this: ```<div class="container body-content">```on the ```Site.Master```, so you have to put only tags like ```<div>``` and other that are nested to a ```<div>```. Then start trying to put a simple ```<div>``` and try others.

Comment: @Felipe Augusto  I see what you mean about the <div> tag in the SIte.Master file, but I don't see how that would help my problem since I already tried that and it still gave me an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153507/discussion-between-felipe-augusto-and-user445555).

Answer (score 2):

You can put HTML elements like this: 
`<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> <div>Test</div> </asp:Content>`.

If you want to edit the   and others and things like that, you can make that inside the `Site.Master`.

But if you want to add other HTML pages you need to make new HTML page and add that inside the page you want(Maybe Default.aspx) , like [this Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file).